# 'delete' not supported spring boot

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, request, http-delete

using Angular 8 and Springboot app... passing value through JSON getting error:
Request delete doesn't supported 
here is the error :

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Dec 05 22:55:04 WET 2019 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not
>   supported

```
 @DeleteMapping("/Emp/{id}")
        public boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
         collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }
```

Component.ts

```
 deleteEmployee() {
    this.employeservice.deleteEmployee(this.employee.id)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));

    this.gotoList();
  }
```

Service :

```
 deleteEmployee( id: number): Observable<Object> {
      return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/Emp/`+id);
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but in vain 
@RequestMapping(value="/Emp/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
     public boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
   collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id);
         return true;
     }

Comment: Please share the Angular code where you're calling this API endpoint

Comment: @MattU component.ts 
 deleteEmployee() {
    this.employeservice.deleteEmployee(this.employee.id)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    
    this.gotoList();
  }

Service:

 deleteEmployee( id: number): Observable<Object> {
      return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/Emp/`+id);
    }

Comment: We'll need to see the `employeeservice.deleteemployee` method, or whatever calls the Angular `HttpClient`. Please edit your question with the code though, instead of using a comment.

Comment: @MattU i edit it, first it should works on server first then i'll see with the client side

Comment: Have you properly configured CORS on the server side?

Comment: @MattU ur talking about origin headers?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind. Looks like you probably configured that. What does the rest of your controller look like?

Comment: @MattU 
RestController
CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
RequestMapping("/api")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which is I have to add Get method besides delete method
Thank you guys :)

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/empdelete/{id}", method= {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET})
 public boolean deleteEmployee( @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't have to do that. If this works, it means somewhere in your Angular code you're sending a `GET` request in stead of a `DELETE`. Since this is nowhere present in your code, it's going to be difficult to help you with properly solving your issue though.

Comment: @g00glen00b I think It's normal cause i just recuperate id from an array so I use it for delete selected employee so im gonna use both of them !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling the REST-Api for deleting an entry with a HTTP-GET request. You have to call this endpoint with HTTP-DELETE, which will prevent the Method not allowed error. Lets say your UI has a call like `get(/Emp/123)`, which should be `delete(/Emp/123)`.

Comment: U mean 
@RequestMapping(value="/Emp/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GEt)
     public boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
   collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id);
         return true;
     }

Comment: No I saw now your comment. Can you add before the boolean return type a `@ResponseBody` like: `@DeleteMapping("/Emp/{id}")
        public @ResponseBody boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
         collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }` or this : `@RequestMapping(value="/Emp/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE) public @ResponseBody boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) { collaborateurRepository.deleteById(id); return true; }`

Comment: @Kindth please update your question to include the angular code that invokes this API endpoint